# What is the most practical way to assess the performance of electrical engineering students in the use of MATLAB?

Tags: code, evaluation, electrical-engineering, assessment

I am teaching a Signal Processing Lab to undergrad students but I am very confused in regard to how I can evaluate and assess their performance.

I have discussed the matter with my colleagues and they gave me a few suggestions but I don't think that those suggestions are very effective

1. Every student should be asked a viva question
2. Every student should be given a task based on MATLAB

As far as suggestion number 1 is concerned, there are approximately 30 students in the class and I will have to repeat my viva questions since I cannot make 30 different questions from a single topic.

As far as suggestion number 2 is concerned, students copy codes from ChatGPT or from their friends. (We cannot ban their internet usage but even if we do, they still will be using it without informing us).

Please give practical/possible and feasible solutions where I don't have to spend extra time as I also have other classes and responsibilities.

Comment: It feels like there's a bit more to the story here -- in particular, it feels like someone is looking for a metric for the ABET process.  Your course might be a place where the students' facility with Matlab is assessed, which is fair, but unless you're actually *teaching* Matlab in your course, it doesn't feel fair to include that latter assessment in the actual course grade.

Answer (score 1):

From a technical solution point of view, this might be beyond Academia scope!

> 2)Every student should be given a task based on MATLAB
> ... As far as suggestion number 2 is concerned,students copy code from gpt or from their friends.( We cannot ban their internet usage,if we ban they still will be using without informing us)

From a teaching and learning approach, a practical solution is leveraging assessment enabler like [SEB: Safe Exam Browser](https://safeexambrowser.org/about_overview_en.html).

You can run in a kiosks mode or integrate with your university's LMS. It should work seamlessly with BYOD.

---

For university teaching using Cisco `Packet Tracer`, see [Adesemowo et al.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/18146627.2016.1186922), for their teaching and learning approach

- Adesemowo, A. K., Johannes, H., Goldstone, S., & Terblanche, K. (2016). [The experience of introducing secure e-assessment in a South African university first-year foundational ICT networking course](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/18146627.2016.1186922). Africa Education Review, 13(1), 67–86.

`MATLAB` will run within `SEB`, just like Adesemowo et al. had students perform their networking exercise in `Packet Tracer` within `SEB`. You can 'restrict' which MAT file gets loaded within `SEB` for assessment.
PS: *I'm guessing, similar to `Packet Tracer`, for `MATLAB`, the `MATLAB` workspace 'assessment file' would've been created in `Test Manager`*.